# Separate last name and firstname using openoffice formula

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a record like

```
Mr. James M. Heilbronner
Bryan Southwick
Ismael G. Pugeda PE
```

I want to insert the lastname as the last word in this example it should be

```
Helbronner
Southwick
PE (I can just manually edit this)
```

and the rest should go into the first name

```
Mr. James M.
Bryan
Ismael G. Pugeda
```

=RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND(" ";SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";" ";LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";""))))) this is my code for the last name but it gets all the words after the first word

edit:

I have the solution for the last name it's this code

=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ";A2));A2;TRIM(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND("*";SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";"*";LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";"")))))))

the only problem is the firstname

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Mr. Heilbronner resides in A2:

B2: `=LEFT(A2;LEN(A2)-LEN(C2))`
C2: `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";REPT(" ";99));99))`

both copied down to suit.

The basic concept I think courtesy of [Jerry Beaucaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196002/jerry-beaucaire): replace all spaces with *lots* of spaces and then chop off a hunk from the end and remove all spaces from it. Once you have the length of the 'surname' then use that to limit the number of characters chosen for the 'first name'.